# DateTime::createFromFormat error

Tags: php, datetime

I want to read a string in a data-format, what is wrong:

```
    $value = "Sat, 07 May 2016 02:00 AM EEST";

    $time = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M Y g:i A', "$value");

    echo $time->format('g:i');
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you have anything in your format to handle the EEST.

Comment: Thx Don't Panic I find the problem: $time = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M Y g:i A T', "$value");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date format string needs to include a timezone identifier to handle the `EEST` part of the string.

```
$value = "Sat, 07 May 2016 02:00 AM EEST";

$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M Y g:i A T', "$value");
                      // Add a timezone identifier ^

echo $time->format('g:i');
```